# how to override primefaces component inline style without using !important in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces component `p:selectonemenu` on one of my webpages. I'm trying to apply style on it using my own css (without using `!important`), but it's not taking the styles from my own external css file. It's taking some inline style from somewhere, but I don't want that component to have that inline style. I want it to use style from my own external css file.

I am not getting from where this inline style is coming. Is this coming from any javascript? I need help here, below is my code.

#### Primefaces Code

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{Controller.property}" id="dropDown">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="0" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{controller.property}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

#### HTML interpreted code

```
<div id="j_idt40" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default 
ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 190px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Is this coming from any javascript?*

That's correct. This inline style is been set by `PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.initWidths` in `primefaces.js`.

The only way to override this without `!important` is to specify the inline style yourself.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... style="width: 500px">
```

You could also override the `PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.initWidths` with a custom JS file, but this would affect all `<p:selectOneMenu>` components.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles have the greatest "specificity", and they override all applicable rules, so your only remedy is `!important` (unless you can override the `style` property value somehow).

**EDIT**: Sorry for overlooking the core question. So, your recipe is as follows:

Insert

> ```
>  <script>
>    debugger;
>  </script>
> ```

at the end of your `<body>`, open DevTools, and load the page.

Now, once you are in your DevTools debugger, switch to the Elements panel, and find the element that receives the inline style. It should not have it just yet.

Right-click this element and in the context menu choose `Break on...` | `Attribute modifications`. Now, when the `style` attribute value changes, you should break on the respective JavaScript line. Good luck!

Comment: :this does not answer my question..i want to know where that inline style coming from and is there anything using which we can ignore inline css for a particular component